# Handle boost endpoint listen/run error

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, websocket++

I can't get an error of endpoint if I set wrong/busy port. I use websocket server that is publicly inherited from boost endpoint. I want handle error here:

```
try {
    m_server.reset(); // leads to some errors/warnings in console, but it works :)
    m_server.listen(777777777);
    m_server.start_accept();

    m_thread = std::thread(&Server::run, &m_server);

    return true;
}
catch (...) {
    m_running = false;
    return false;
}
```

I tried m_server.is_listening(), m_server.stopped() etc, but they show same result for both norm/bad port number. How can I handle error?

UPD1: I use [websocketpp](http://www.zaphoyd.com/websocketpp) library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try catching exceptions of type `websocketpp::exception` and calling the `code()` method on them. This should return a specific error code that you can inspect to see if it is a "wrong/busy port" or some other error.

Alternatively, if you want to avoid exceptions, most methods (such as listen) will accept a second error code parameter and will fill that in with the error code that would have been set in the exception.

Comment: I forgot reply my solution here.